# bind(): Operation not permitted on Nginx

Tags: nginx, cygwin

I just installed Nginx on my machine to run Nginx. After install and config. I try to run nginx and got this problem:

```
bind() to 0.0.0.0:8843 failed (1:Operation not permitted)
```

I have no idea what this problem is and how to fix it. Google cannot find any related result also.

Is there anyway to fix?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A random guess would be that either

- The account you are using doesn't have permissions to open the port you have specified
- The port is already in use.

Try temporarily disabling any firewalls and any kernel level security apps (apparmor/selinux).  Use `netstat -ntlp` to see if anything else is already using the port.

Comment: As you notice the "permission" word. I found the answer. Read below:

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it's because of the permission that run CYGWIN.

On Windows 7 or Vista, need to **run CYGWIN as administrator** to be able to bind this port.